# equation system: which $k$ will yield infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Determine such values ​​of k that the equation system has infinitely
>   many solutions. How many parameters these solutions depend on.
>   $\begin{cases}x+2y-3z+t=1\\x+4y+3z+4t=-4\\x-4y-21z-8t=k\end{cases}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-3&1|&1\\1&4&3&4|&-4\\1&-4&-21&-8|&k\end{bmatrix}$...after transformations i got $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-3&1|&1\\0&1&3&\frac{3}{2}|&-\frac{5}{2}\\0&0&1&0|&\frac{k-16}{-6}\end{bmatrix}$
I don't know what to do next to finish the task

Comment: The system is underdetermined, so it either has no solution or an infinite number of them. Looking at the reduced matrix, can you find any way to make the system inconsistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a(x+2y-3z+t)+b(x+4y+3z+4t)=x-4y-21z-8t,$

then $a+b=1$ and $2a+4b=-4$, so $a=\color{blue}4$ and $b=\color{purple}{-3}$.

If you multiply the first equation by $\color{blue}4$ and the second equation by $\color{purple}{-3}$ and add them,

you will get the third equation when $k=\,?$

Comment: it will be $k=16$?

Comment: $k=16$ is correct (note the lower right of your augmented matrix)

Comment: does anything else need to accomplish this task? I didn't know your way with a and b very fast before

Comment: Before I answer further questions, I'd like to know why the down vote

Comment: I have no idea and will give you up vote

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

1. When will the system have infinite solutions rather than no
   solution? Or, when will $k$ cause inconsistency of the system
   ($0=\text{non-zero number}$, which is impossible)?  (Think: Why there cannot be a unique
   solution?)
2. After finding $k$ that assures the system has infinite
       solutions, you can solve equations by setting free parameters as
       usual.